# How to process an array IN PARALLEL

Tags: iphone, cocoa

So there's a number of ways to run all the elements of an array through a selector or block of code. `makeObjectsPerformSelector:` and more

If you have 4 or 16 cores on hand, you may well want to send all the processing off to different processes.

Even on iOS, it could well be sensible to send them all away, or at least let them be finished whichever way the wind blows.

**What is the best and neatest way** to do this in the cocoa milieu?

Again, what if you want to send them away to be finished at any time, i.e., ***do not wait for the enumeration to finish before executing the following instruction***...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can target iOS 4+ or Mac OS X 10.6+, use Grand Central Dispatch (and I'm using a category because I think they're cool):

```
#import <dispatch/dispatch.h>

@interface NSArray (DDAsynchronousAdditions)

- (void) makeObjectsPerformSelectorAsynchronously:(SEL)selector;
- (void) makeObjectsPerformSelectorAsynchronously:(SEL)selector withObject:(id)object;

@end

@implementation NSArray (DDAsynchronousAdditions)

- (void) makeObjectsPerformSelectorAsynchronously:(SEL)selector {
  [self makeObjectsPerformSelectorAsynchronously:selector withObject:nil];
}

- (void) makeObjectsPerformSelectorAsynchronously:(SEL)selector withObject:(id)object {
  for (id element in self) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
      [element performSelector:selector withObject:object];
    });
  }
}

@end

//elsewhere:

[myArray makeObjectsPerformSelectorAsynchronously:@selector(doFoo)];
```

Or, if you don't want to use a category...

```
[myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL * stop) {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
    [obj performSelector:@selector(doFoo)];
  };
}];
```

Comment: @Joe I answered it yesterday :)

Comment: @Joe the `0,0` are for getting the global queue of default priority (`0`), and the second parameter is always 0 (because the docs say so).  And if you have a block in a variable `myBlock`, you invoke it like so:  `myBlock()`

Comment: What is the advantage of Dave DeLong’s category over -enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:?

Comment: @Bavarious I forgot about it :)

Comment: Aside from the objection of "use the API instead of inventing equivalents to it", my other objection to the category here is that it conflates the ideas of "asynchronous" and "concurrent". They're different, and that difference is important.

Comment: @Catfish_Man yes there is a difference between "asynchronous" and "concurrent", and though my answer shows a "concurrent" method, you can't be concurrent without being asynchronous.  So while it's perhaps not perfectly named, it's not named *incorrectly*.

Comment: Actually you can be concurrent without being asynchronous. -[NSArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] and its underlying dispatch_apply() are concurrent, but not asynchronous. You call them, they run until done, and then they return. The key question is "after this line, can I rely on the work having been done yet?".

Comment: That said, yes, yours is both asynchronous and concurrent.

Comment: If you don't impose some sort of throttling on that "dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ...)" line, you'll create an explosion of threads to service the global concurrent dispatch queue.

Comment: @Jon nope.  that's the whole *point* of grand central dispatch.  It queues it up on the global thread, and they execute whenever they execute.

Comment: Weeeeell, no. Not exactly. Try it :) (it depends on what the work in the blocks is, basically. If they're compute-bound then yes, dispatch should do its thing. If you do any IO or block in them, you'll get a thread explosion capped at 512 threads)

Comment: @Catfish_Man - True, I/O bounds tasks could jam things up, like Mike Ash describes here: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-09-25-gcd-practicum.html , and that's where dispatch semaphores come into play.

Answer (score 10):

If you want concurrency and synchronous behaviour (i.e., wait for the enumeration to finish before executing the following instruction), `-[NSArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]` will do that if you pass the `NSEnumerationConcurrent` option. This method is available on Mac OS 10.6+ and iOS 4.0+.

If you want asynchronous behaviour, you can use one of the standard multithreading solutions such as NSOperation or GCD combined with `-enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:`. For instance,

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    [array enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent
        usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            // do something with obj
        }];
    });
```

Comment: The whole point of that option is to spread the work across available cores. What else could it do?

Comment: That method uses GCD internally, but it does some batching of work to avoid unnecessary overhead. I would recommend trying it before rolling your own.

Comment: @Joe Blow: you can use any of the usual solutions for multithreading, such as NSOperation or GCD. For instance, you could GCD-async-dispatch a block that sends `-enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:` to the array.

Comment: @Joe Blow: Yup, Dave’s code dispatches the blocks for asynchronous execution. The iteration over the array is _synchronous_, although it would only make a noticeable difference for large arrays.

Comment: Well, you could at least wrap the iteration in dispatch_async instead of vice versa. i.e. dispatch_async(..., ^{ [array enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:^{ ... }]; }); instead of [array enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:^{ dispatch_async(..., ^{ ... }); }]; The former also saves you N -copy calls on the inner block over the latter. As for iterating the array concurrently... non-mutable NSArrays are threadsafe, so I guess you could divide it into chunks and iterate the chunks in parallel manually. Probably not worth it though.

Comment: Oh hey, Bavarious edited his example to say this already didn't he. Wish I'd noticed that before doing all that typing.

Comment: @Joe - If you want to experiment with this, I have a simple test application I created for my course that demonstrates Dave's and (a variant of ) Bavarious' approaches: http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/ThreadingExample.zip .  Look in the MATCGCD.m file, where both approaches can be turned on and off using comments.  For a compute-bound task, they will be effectively identical (dispatch in the background, return immediately, and process items in an array in parallel).  You can watch how tasks are performed in real time using this example.