# Idiomatic way to execute an array of blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I have an object that can execute an arbitrary queue of updates. I use blocks to embody the updates.  I add an update using my `addUpdate:` method.

```
- (void) addUpdate: (void(^)())block {
    [self.updates addObject: block];
}
```

Later, I want to execute all of them. I don't care if they run concurrently or not. The basic primitive way would seem to be something like:

```
for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < self.updates.count; index++) {
    void (^block)() = self.updates[index];
    block();
}
```

or with fast enumeration

```
for (void (^block)() in self.updates) {
    block();
}
```

Or is there something I should be doing with GCD to make this happen?

Comment: I think `NSOperation` is better fits to this case. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004591

Comment: Here's a really old question on this, for historic interest!  http://stackoverflow.com/q/4588289/294884  Note Brad's excellent example program in a comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most terse way I can think of to do this would be:

```
[self.updates makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(invoke)];
```

How "idiomatic" that is will probably be situation-dependent...

EDIT: This depends on the fact that blocks are implemented in the runtime as Objective-C objects, and respond to the selector `-invoke`. In other words, the expression `block();` can also be expressed as `[block invoke];`. I'm not aware of any more succinct way to execute an array of blocks.

Comment: mmmm... this topic is about _blocks_ not _selectors_.

Comment: Blocks are implemented in the runtime as Objective-C objects, and respond to the selector `-invoke`. In other words, the expression `block();` can also be expressed as `[block invoke];`. I'm not aware of any more *succinct* way to execute an array of blocks.

Answer (score 2):

For non-concurrent execution, for-in is the way to go. For concurrent execution, you could use NSArray's -enumerateUsing... methods and pass the concurrent flag, or use dispatch_apply() instead of a loop.